# How to change font size in console application using C

Tags: c

How can I change the font size of a printed font using c?

```
 printf ("%c", map[x][y]);
```

I want to print an array larger than all the other text in the program. Is there a way to just make that statement print larger?

Comment: It seems unlikely. The console subsystem of the system you are on will dictate the font. You are just writing unformatted strings to the standard output stream, and the system does with that what it wants to.

Comment: You could use ASCII art. However, the font is, as SirPentor already told you, set by the console subsystem.

Comment: Take a look at [ncurses](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although [teppic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316455/how-to-change-font-size-in-console-application-using-c/15316588#15316588) to use `system()` will work, it is rather intensively heavy-handed to call an external program just to do that. As for [David RF' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316455/how-to-change-font-size-in-console-application-using-c/15316679#15316679), it is hard-coded for a specific type of terminal (probably a VT100-compatible terminal type) and won't support the user's actual terminal type.

In C, you should use terminfo capabilities directly:

```
#include <term.h>

/* One-time initialization near the beginning of your program */
setupterm(NULL, STDOUT_FILENO, NULL);

/* Enter bold mode */
putp(enter_bold_mode);

printf("I am bold\n");

/* Turn it off! */
putp(exit_attribute_mode);
```

Still, as [teppic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1627348/teppic) notes, there is no support for changing the font size. That's under the user's control.

Comment: I agree it's a lot just to call it, but it's very portable (within OSes that have the command) and easy in simple programs.

Comment: Actually, `setterm` is not portable, it's Linux-specific. `tput` is the portable command you are looking for. And `tput` will just use terminfo as I've demonstrated so you might as well do it directly. termcap/terminfo and the `$TERM` environment variable have existed for decades and are pretty much available on almost every operating system.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't realise it was only found in Linux. I do mean only for simple programs though, where external libraries and functions to manipulate the terminal quickly become hard to remember. I'd never suggest this for 'proper' code.

Answer (score 1):

If it's Linux (and probably other forms of Unix) you could mess around with `system` to change a few terminal settings to make it stand out - though not the font size. This kind of thing would really only be suitable for simple programs, and it's obviously not portable:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

[...]

printf("Normal text\n");
system("setterm -bold on");
printf("Bold text\n");
system("setterm -bold off");
```

Otherwise there are various terminal sequences you can send directly via `printf` that will control most Unix terminal applications, e.g. `\033[31m` will change the text to red in an xterm. But these sequences can vary.

Answer (score 1):

If you are under some unix, you can try to activate and deactivate bold text:

```
printf("\033[1m%c\033[0m", map[x][y]);
```

Comment: This, unfortunately, is hard-coded to a specific terminal type.

Comment: Yes, I know ;) I usually use it via xterm

Answer (score 0):

This code will work on Win32 applications (regardless of the subsystem used: WINDOWS or CONSOLE):

```
inline void setFontSize(int a, int b) 

{

    HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    PCONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX lpConsoleCurrentFontEx = new CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX();

    lpConsoleCurrentFontEx->cbSize = sizeof(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX);

    GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hStdOut, 0, lpConsoleCurrentFontEx);

    lpConsoleCurrentFontEx->dwFontSize.X = a;

    lpConsoleCurrentFontEx->dwFontSize.Y = b;

    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hStdOut, 0, lpConsoleCurrentFontEx);

}
```

Then just call (for example):

```
setFontSize(20,20);
```