# How to set different font attributes to a text output in C/C++?

Tags: c, fonts

Given the following basic C program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
     printf("Hellow World!");

     return 0;
}
```

How to set different font attributes (size, weight, slope) for the output `Hello World!`? I have read answers to related questions like [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316455/how-to-change-font-size-in-console-application-using-c) but suggested solutions do not answer my question.

I will appreciate your help. Thank in advance.

Note: I am working under Mac OS (macOS High Sierra) and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS; using the terminal.

Comment: The answers in the link you provided say: It is not possible to change the size, and I think this applies to weight etc. You can only set attributes like bold, blinking, underline etc.

Comment: If you need to improve the output, you will need to use a third party lib like ncurses for example